# WooCommerce Payment custom thank you page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce to handle orders on my WordPress
and I'm using a custom payment gateway plugin. everything works perfectly except that I want to modify the thank you page which tells the customer that the order has been successfully registered.

The process payment function:

```
public function process_payment( $order_id ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    // Mark as on-hold (we're awaiting the cheque)
    $order->update_status('on-hold', __( 'Awaiting payment', 'woocommerce-other-payment-gateway' ));
    // Reduce stock levels
    $order->reduce_order_stock();
    if(isset($_POST[ $this->id.'-admin-note']) && trim($_POST[ $this->id.'-admin-note'])!=''){
        $order->add_order_note(esc_html($_POST[ $this->id.'-admin-note']),1);
    }
    // Remove cart
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
    // Return thankyou redirect
    return array(
        'result' => 'success',
        'redirect' => $this->get_return_url( $order )
    );  
}
```

I want when the user sees the thank you page they will be automatically redirected after it.

I don't want to change the redirect URL on the array like:

```
'redirect' => 'http://example.com/'
```

I want to redirect them after they see the page, how can I manage to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First you want to show default thank you page and then you want to redirect the user to your custom thank you page, right?

Comment: @MahaDev Exactly

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It seems like bad UX to redirect people without their input. How do you know when someone is done reading it?
 Why don't you create a custom thank you page, or add your custom info to the existing thank you page.

Answer (score 0):

You can right some js code to redirect to your custom success page like this:

```
<script>

setTimeout(function(){ 
   //redirect after 3 seconds
    window.location.href= 'your_custom_url';

}, 3000);

</script>
```

You need to write this code on default thank you page.

Comment: i think inside the woocommerce/checkout/thankyou.php

Comment: hey thank you for your answer , just one more thing about the 'Types' in the init_fields `$this->form_fields = array(
     'enabled' => array(
     'title'   => __( 'Enable/Disable', 'woocommerce-other-payment-gateway' ),
     'type'    => 'checkbox',
     'label'   => __( 'Enable Custom Payment', 'woocommerce-other-payment-gateway' ),
     'default'   => 'yes'
     ),`if i want to insert html/js code what type should i use ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to tell your customers that the order is successfully registered, there are two way to achieve that.

### Option 1

You can hook the default WooCommerce thank you page. Example

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'anycustomfunc', 4 );

// OR (better way)
// add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_{PAYMENT GATEWAY SLUG}', 'anycustomfunc', 4 );

function anycustomfunc( $order_id ) {

    echo 'Your order has been successfully registered!';

}
```

### Option 2

Redirect customers to a completely different page when they use the specific payment gateway.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_thankyou' );

function redirect_to_thankyou(){

    if( !is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // $o is an order object
    $o = wc_get_order( wc_get_order_id_by_order_key( $_GET['key'] ) );

    if( 'the payment method slug here' == $o->get_payment_method() ) { 
        wp_redirect( 'any custom url' );
        exit;
    }
}
```

You can find the payment gateway slug in your WooCommerce settings. Both of the examples I took from this tutorial https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/thank-you-page.html